# How to define hyper-schema version?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm developing an API with [hyper-schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html) support. How can I define the API version? Is there any best practice for this? I'm thinking to use a proprietary "version" field but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there exist a recommended solution, but the most standard way I guess would be to use Accept http header.

You may define your API content type, something like vnd.apitag+json and then use version to be able to ask for different versions:

> Accept: application/vnd.yourapi+json; version=3

Obviously you will have to manage that in your backend. Be aware that this solution is [advised against by some people](http://pivotallabs.com/api-versioning/). Well, [versioning tends to be discouraged](http://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning) but this is opinionated.

I suggest you have a look to [heroku use of json-schema](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/5/20/heroku-http-api-toolchain) for the definition of their API.